# Duplicate Order Creation in Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: orders, paypal, ce-1.9.1.0, duplicate

I am getting an issue with Paypal standard for few customers.
When payment received there are two orders logged in magento. Both of which go into payment pending status and then subsequently one is released into processing state and the other remains in pending payment state.

Can anyone share me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When customer created into website at that time function of "Customer Password Timestamp" was missing there and page redirects to HomePage instead of  "Paypal Page".

Solution: Function "Customer Password Timestamp" added into variean file.